# Visual Studio- moving local database

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an app in VS which includes a SQL database stored locally on my C drive. I can publish the app and it works fine on my own computer, but because the database is stored locally, I cannot run the app from any other computer (SQL exception 52). I would like to move the app to a network drive so it can be accessed by multiple users.

I have tried to move the database by changing the default database location in the SQL server object explorer. I’m wondering if I should have SQL server express LocalDB installed?

I have no programming training but have been dumped with this project at work as I have used VBA before, so I’m sorry if this question it stupid. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: to do this properly you'd really want a SQL Server instance which is on an actual server, not someone's desktop machine, and place the live copy of the database there. And ideally you'd install a copy of the app on the machine of each person who wants to use it, although I guess it might be possible to run it from a network drive, just might not perform very well

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "a SQL database"? What DB are you using exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing your database, rather than using just the database name, you should specify the filepath aswell, like this:

```
Public Filename As String = $"[**FilePath**]ActiveFitness.accdb"
```

This tells the programme where to look for the database, and is better practice than relying on the default location.

Comment: Well, I guess it wasn't SQL Server after all. It was Access; a file based database not a server based database.